# Why doesn't this math work with macros?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Why doesn't this math work with macros in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO 6
#define BAR 32
#define MULT FOO * BAR

main() {
    int x = 28296;
    int y = x / MULT;
    printf("%d / %d = %d\n", x, MULT, y);

    return 0;
}
```

The result of this is:

```
28296 / 192 = 150912
```

Why isn't it 147?  If I set a variable " int mult" equal to MULT, and use the variable in the expression (`int y = x / mult`) it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a bracket around the macro:

```
#define MULT (FOO * BAR)
```

Now, you'll get 147.

The reason getting `150912` is that after macro expansion the expression is equivalent to:

```
y = 28296 / 6 * 32;
```

and hence it's evaluated as `28296/6` and then multiplied by`32`.

As @kevin points out, it's better to put brackets around `FOO` and `BAR` as well in general case to avoid surprises like this.

Comment: He'd do well to parenthesize `(FOO)` and `(BAR)` as well.

Comment: After the preprocessing the expression is expanded as `y = x / 6 * 32`. The macro preprocessor works basically as a text editor.

Comment: @Kevin: Even better to not use macros for constants at all.

Comment: @Kevin: There's no need to parenthesize `FOO` and `BAR` in this case, since they're not macro parameters, and they expand to single tokens (and if they don't, then their definitions should be parenthesized). The guidelines for macros that expand to a valid expression, the guidelines are: 1. Put parentheses around the entire definition, and 2. For function-like macros, parenthesize each reference to a macro parameter.

Comment: @GManNickG: Why not use macros for constants? A `const` object declaration doesn't create a constant expression (in C; C++ is different), and the enum hack `enum { MAX = 1024 };` only works for constants of type `int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Didn't see I wound up in the C tag. :)

Answer (score 4):

`#define` tells the preprocessor to replace the code before compilation, so your line actually says:

```
int y = x / 6 * 32;
```

since * and / operators have the same precedence, and are evaluated from left to right, you get (x/6) * 32. The compiler would probably do this calculation for you since x is known to it.

Instead, use parenthesis when defining macros like this